# Creating Segment Dynamically in AWS X-RAY SDK .NET

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-xray

Well, I'm just start right now to instrument my .NET Core application with X-Ray, adding the following in Startup.cs:

```
AWSXRayRecorder.InitializeInstance(Configuration);
AWSSDKHandler.RegisterXRayForAllServices();
```

And

```
app.UseXRay("myApp"); //to get HTTP requests
```

All httpRequests are intercepted and logged in XRay console as I expected. But in the same project I have a listener consuming RabbitMQ messages, so I have a MessageHandler.

I know that XRay don't instrument automatically this MessageHandler because I need to create a segment. I know that I can do something like this:

```
AWSXRayRecorder.Instance.BeginSegment("MyMethodABC"); 
... 
AWSXRayRecorder.Instance.EndSegment();
```

But I would like to know if exist a automatic way to do it without need to make this BeginSegment in each method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to instrument RabbitMQ calls except manually begin/end segment/subsegment around the logic.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-dotnet.html